# How to add ruby on rails model validation for two fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

```
#  columns
#  maximum_users           :integer(4)
#  last_registration_date  :datetime

class Training < ApplicationRecord

 validates :maximum_users, numericality: { greater_than: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 999,  
            only_integer: true }

 validate :last_reg_date_cannot_be_in_the_past



   private
   def last_reg_date_cannot_be_in_the_past
    if last_registration_date_changed? && last_registration_date < Time.now.utc
      errors.add(:training, "can't be in the past")
    end
  end

end
```

In the above model I need to add followings validations:

1. If user selects any one of the field than other should be nil (`maximum_users` or `last_registration_date`).
2. User cannot add both the fields values.
3. User can choose not to select any of the values. But if he chooses then, anyone field must be allowed.
4. `maximum_users` allowed is less than `999`.
5. `last_registration_date` must be greater than today's date.

I have added few validations but don't think this is a good practice.

How can I refactor the model to cover all the above scenarios ?

Comment: I would suggest you will do it in 1 custom validation, as you can validate both fields there.

Comment: It will be a lengthy validation for the above scenario. Is there any way to shorten these ?

Comment: I think only rule that could be used via `validates` is 4th, maybe 5th. Others have to be in custom, so I would suggest do it all in custom validation. Yeah, it will be long, but more readable and maintable. But maybe I am wrong and it can be done via `validates`

Comment: You might be able to do some conditional validations on each column. Like validate presence, if ... https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#combining-validation-conditions

Comment: @vikas95prasad RE: "It will be a lengthly validation" -- Yes, this is why I would also recommend a custom validation rather than trying to inline all of this with "clever" (but confusing and error-prone) `if: [Proc.new(...), ...]` logic. More specifically, I would advise defining a [*custom validator class*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators) where you can split all of this logic (especially requirements 1-3) into clean methods, and write/test it all in isolation.

Answer (score 1):

Having plenty of validations is not a bad practice.  At some point you may want to move it to a validator class.

```
class Training < ApplicationRecord
 validates_with TrainingValidator
end
```

One problem I see with what you have is that `last_registration_date` can be set and `maximum_users` be nil, but your `maximum_users` validation above might not allow nil.

```
app/models/concerns/traning_validator.rb

classTrainingValidator < ActiveModel::Validator 

  def validate(training)
    if training.last_registration_date_changed? && training.last_registration_date < Time.now.utc
      training.errors.add(:training, "can't be in the past")
    end

    unless training.last_registration_date.nil? || training.maximum_users.nil?
      training.errors.add(:last_registration_date, "last_registration_date cannot both be set when maximum_users is set")
    end

    unless training.maximum_users.nil? || training.maximum_users < 999
      training.errors.add(:maximum_users, "must be less than 999")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you suggest changes to my solution @Marlin

Comment: Same code, but under a private method like you had.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this :

```
class NotInPastValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors.add attribute, (options[:message] || "Date can't be in the past") if value <= Time.now.utc
  end
end
```

Model :

```
 validates :maximum_users,
            numericality: {
              greater_than: 0,
              less_than_or_equal_to: 999,
              only_integer: true
            }
  validates :last_registration_date, not_in_past: true
  validate :validate_max_users_and_last_reg_date


  def validate_max_users_and_last_reg_date
    if maximum_users_changed? && last_registration_date_changed?
      errors.add(:training, 'Specify either maximum users or last registration date, not both')
    end
  end

  def maximum_users_changed?
    changes.keys.include? 'maximum_users'
  end

  def last_registration_date_changed?
    changes.keys.include? 'last_registration_date'
  end
```